# Same Facebook application to multiple pages

Tags: facebook, tabpage

I have created a Facebook application and added it to a tab in my Facebook page. The problem is that I want to add the same app to another page and I don't know how to distinguish  from which of the two pages the request comes.

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the signed_request parameter for that, it includes information about the page (id, admin): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/